# Using check in discord-rewrite cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So this is my code that I have in my discord-rewrite cog, I read the code how the `cog_check` from the [Github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/discord/ext/commands/cog.py#L256), but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

```
@commands.command()
async def mee(msg):
    await msg.send("ME")
```

An example of the function usage or explanation on it would be nice.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check)

```py
def is_me():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id == 85309593344815104
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command()
@is_me()
async def only_me(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Only you!')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's defined based on name.  You need to supply a `cog_check` coroutine to override the one inherited from `Cog`

```
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, command

class MyCog(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        return True  # Whatever check you want to do
    @command()
    async def mee(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("ME")
```

Comment: Is there a way to only use the check on a single command inside a cog, or is there only a way to apply to all commands inside a cog?

Comment: You can apply a check to individual command normally, using the decorator syntax.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost on it, could you please show me an example by editing your answer? It would help a lot.!